# Cinema 4d - Cannot rig mesh to skeleton

Tags: binding, mesh, cinema-4d

I am trying to bind a skeleton to a mesh.

I cannot seem to be able to do this as the button stays disabled.

This is my setup:

[image: Player]

[image: Project Setup]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the SKIN stays underneath the MESH in the list.

Something like this:

[image: Cinema4d - Default setup to bind skin to bone]

I'm pretty sure this might be your issue.

Let me know if it works.